# Retreiving values from HashMap<String, String> for each character of a string returns NULL

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I'm learning Java and as a project I'm trying to make a program that uses a `HashMap` to accept a `string` from the user then return the corresponding (pseudo-Pinyin) values as a quasi-encrypted `String`.

I got this to work when the `String` was just 1 `character` in length, but my many attempts to handle full sentence failed.

In a prior SO Question, this was marked as duplicate (and I deleted the question), but the prior related solution:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < args.length(); i++){
     char c = args.charAt(i);        
     s += lookup.get(c);
     s += " "; 
 }
```

Actually doesn't solve my problem.

The best result I've been able to get using the `for` loop indicated as a previously posted solution was to return a string that prints `null` for every character entered by the user. For example, `hello` becomes `null null null null null`.

Here's the relevant part of the code (`Encrypt2Pinyin.java`):

```
package pinyincrypto;
import java.util.*;

public class Encrypt2Pinyin {

public static String e2p(String args){
HashMap<String, String> lookup = new HashMap<>();
lookup.put("a", "xuduo");
lookup.put("b", "bai");
lookup.put("c", "cai");
lookup.put("d", "dai");
lookup.put("e", "tao");
lookup.put("f", "nao");
lookup.put("g", "lao");
lookup.put("h", "zheng");
lookup.put("i", "ceng");
lookup.put("j", "sheng");
lookup.put("k", "peng");
lookup.put("l", "che");
lookup.put("m", "shui");
lookup.put("n", "ge");
lookup.put("o", "zhi");
lookup.put("p", "nu");
lookup.put("q", "ren");
lookup.put("r", "nan");
lookup.put("s", "hai");
lookup.put("t", "xihuan");
lookup.put("u", "wo");
lookup.put("v", "wu");
lookup.put("w", "chi");
lookup.put("x", "niu");
lookup.put("y", "duo");
lookup.put("z", "yunxing");
lookup.put("A", "Xuduo");
lookup.put("B", "Bai");
lookup.put("C", "Cai");
lookup.put("D", "Dai");
lookup.put("E", "Tao");
lookup.put("F", "Nao");
lookup.put("G", "Lao");
lookup.put("H", "Zheng");
lookup.put("I", "Ceng");
lookup.put("J", "Sheng");
lookup.put("K", "Peng");
lookup.put("L", "Che");
lookup.put("M", "Shui");
lookup.put("N", "Ge");
lookup.put("O", "Zhi");
lookup.put("P", "Nu");
lookup.put("Q", "Ren");
lookup.put("R", "Nan");
lookup.put("S", "Hai");
lookup.put("T", "Xihuan");
lookup.put("U", "Wo");
lookup.put("V", "Wu");
lookup.put("W", "Chi");
lookup.put("X", "Niu");
lookup.put("Y", "Duo");
lookup.put("Z", "Yunxing");
lookup.put(" ", " ");
lookup.put(".", "?");
lookup.put("!", ".");
lookup.put("?", "!");
lookup.put("$", "%");
lookup.put("%", "$");
lookup.put("@", "&");
lookup.put("&", "@");
lookup.put("#", "*");
lookup.put("*", "#");
lookup.put("^", "]");
lookup.put("(", ")");
lookup.put(")", "(");
lookup.put("-", "-");
lookup.put("=", "+");
lookup.put("+", "=");
lookup.put("\n", "\n");
lookup.put(" ", " ");
//Vector vec = new Vector();
//vec.add(args);
//Iterator<HashMap<K, V>> itr = lookup.values().iterator();
//String[] vec = args;
//Vector<String> vector = null;
//while (itr.hasNext())
//{
//vector=(vec)itr.next();
//  }

//String[] str   = null;
//s = args.split("(?!^)") ;

String s   = " ";
//String str = args.trim();
for (int i = 0; i < args.length(); i++){
    char c = args.charAt(i);        
        s += lookup.get(c);
        s += " ";
}
//return(lookup.get(args.charAt(1))); // just a test -- still returns null
return(s);
}
}
```

If it's useful I can also provide the corresponding code for the `.java` file containing my `main` function.

Comment: `char` and `String` data types are different in Java. It seems that you're trying to retrieve something from the map by passing in a `char`..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your map has `String` as key, you cannot use a `char`

```
char c = args.charAt(i);  
s += lookup.get(c);      // you are giving char as key, what is not valid!!!
```

Use this workaround:

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.length(); i++){
    char c = args.charAt(i);        
    s += lookup.get(c+"");
    //                 ↑ ugly but converts char to String
    s += " ";
}
```

Or this one, more polite:

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.length(); i++){
    String c = Character.toString(args.charAt(i));
    s += lookup.get(c);
    s += " ";
}
```

Comment: Why not use `String.valueOf(char);` instead.

Comment: @Kayaman updated answer, just used `char+""` because OP said: *I'm learning Java*

Comment: Thank very much to you and to @resueman as well I have upvoted both answers and will mark this as the solution once enough time has passed to do so

Answer (score 2):

It is returning `null` because you have declared your map as `HashMap<String, String> lookup` with `String` as **the type for your key** and then you are trying to retrieve using a `char`

```
char c = args.charAt(i);        
s += lookup.get(c);
```

which is why it is returning `null`.

So use this instead :

```
 char c = args.charAt(i);        
 s += lookup.get(new String(c));
```

Comment: Another good solution. Someone else answered first but I can give you a +1 and my thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach is that the keys in the map are of type `String`, while the keys that you are using for the lookup are of type `char`.

You can solve it in two ways:

- Convert the `char` to `String` - for example, by concatenating it with `""`, calling `toString`, or using `valueOf` method, or
- Changing the map to `HashMap<Character,String>`.

The first approach (converting `char` to `String` is slightly more wasteful, because it makes lots of throw-away one-character strings. Although accessing by `char` requires boxing, `Character` class *interns* all the characters that your code is using, and reuses the same object for its boxing conversion. This eliminates the waste.

The second approach is a lot cleaner, and it would let you keep the lookups unchanged. All you need to change is the insertions:

```
Map<Character,String> lookup = new HashMap<>();
lookup.put('a', "xuduo");
lookup.put('b', "bai");
lookup.put('c', "cai");
...
```

Everything else would continue to work without additional changes.